# Linking battle net account to psn

Tags: psn, battle.net, blizzard

Now, with the Overwatch free weekend I downloaded Overwatch for PS4. In the store it seemed like it's Origin's edition.
According to this [answer](https://eu.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/17611741017#post-8) I should get Origins edition cosmetics if I link it.

The question is: will this free weekend version of Overwatch on PS4 count as Origin's edition? Will I be able to collect the nice skins on my PC if I link them?

Comment: Blizzard can tell when you've bought the game versus when you're using it via a free weekend.

Answer (score 2):

According to this link below you cannot redeem any skins you get on PS4 to PC, even if you have the origin editon, they are actually completely independent from each other. I believe especially not for a free weekend "edition"

https://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20754877443

Comment: More specifically, linking your PSN and BattleNet accounts is to give you cosmetics in the *other* Blizzard games on PC when you buy Origins/Anniversary edition on PS4.